# How do I calculate the distance by road between two geographic locations using Ruby(on Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I have set up a system that calculates the distance between two locations using  http://www.rubygeocoder.com/, however, to be able to calculate the (tax-deductible) kilometer-costs (e.g travel compensation) I would need to get distance by road, for example by using Google.

How is this best done?

Comment: Gmaps4rails includes a ruby wrapper for google direction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/.

For example a request to:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false
```

will get you the directions from Toronto to Montreal and along with it the total distance.

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails wraps the directions API so you might find that it makes your life easier. You might also find that it is overkill in this case since we're only talking about a single request.